# get variable inside the function

Tags: javascript

hello i'm new in javascript I just want to ask if it is possible to get the value inside a function?

sample code

```
function a(){
  var sample = "hello world"
};
```

then i will go to the global context and get the variable `sample`

```
sample2 = sample
console.log(sample2);
```

And when i console.log sample2 then the value of sample2 should be "hello world" please share your knowledge i want to learn more in javascript thanks in advance

Comment: No. It will not. `sample` will loose its scope once `a` has completed execution. If you wish to set `sample`'s value to `sample2` return `sample` inside `a` and then do `sample2 = a()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like any other programming language all you need to do is to return the value that you need to access. So either you can make your function return the variable value and that way you can access it. Or make it return a object which further has sub functions with which you can return the value

So following the first approach,

```
function a() {
    var sample = "hello world";
    return sample;
}

var sample2 = a();
console.log(sample2); //This prints hello world
```

Or, you can use the second approach where you can alter the private variable by exposing secondary functions like

```
function a() {
    var sample = "hello world";
    return {
        get : function () {
            return sample;
        },
        set : function (val) {
            sample = val;
        }
    }
}

//Now you can call the get function and set function separately
var sample2 = new a();
console.log(sample2.get()); // This prints hello world

sample2.set('Force is within you'); //This alters the value of private variable sample

console.log(sample2.get()); // This prints Force is within you
```

Hope this solves your doubt.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to have the function returning a value

```
function a(){
  var sample = "hello world";
  return sample;
}
sample2 = a();
console.log(sample2);
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways of doing this and by far the best way is to declare your variables outside the function, then assign them inside the function.

```
var sample;
var myname;

function a() {
    sample = "Hello World";
    myname = "Solly M";
}

console.log(sample);
console.log(myname);
```